# magento 2 dashboard contents are not working?

Tags: magento2, windows

magento 2 dashboard sidebar is not working???
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go in the `app/etc/di.xml`

Search below line

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

Replace that with below line and check

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run deployment script on shell for backend and check again

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```